# Embedding whole directory structure

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource

I have a large directory structure with JavaScript, images, etc. that depend on each other.  I would like to encapsulate it all into a DLL so I only have to reference one thing and not have multiple copies of all these files across projects.

Because the files depend on each other, I'm thinking I can create an `IHttpModule` that registers a route to accept URLs such as `/MyEmbeddedDir/subdir/file.js`.  Anything in MyEmbeddedDir would then be handled by a custom `IHttpHandler` that does the correct mapping.  Each web application would then need to reference the DLL and add the module and handler to web.config.  Does this seem reasonable?

Also, is there an easier way to embed/reference the files than to set the build action to embedded resource <strike>and add `[assembly: WebResource(...)]` to each file</strike> (there are dozens!)?  Thanks!

**Edit:** If I'm not using WebResource.axd then I shouldn't need to add `[assembly: WebResource(...)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the `IHTTPModule` (register route) and `IHTTPHandler` (obtain embedded resource).  The route is configurable in `web.config` in case it conflicts with existing content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having a single container is a great way to manage large number of files (and no, SQLite won't help here! ;).

We have a product, named [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/), which is a virtual file system, that lets you keep your data in custom storage (resource DLL is one of the options) and provides file API for accessing the files. We even implemented asynchronous pluggable protocol for IE (on the client side, but the task is very similar to yours). SolFS includes a manager application that lets you easily create container files and import files into container.

Comment: Your solution seems good for a bigger system than I am working with.